# Only one expression can be specified in the SELECT list where the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following code - it's odd because I seem to only have one expression in my `SELECT` list at the top, but I am still getting an error stating that only one condition can be specified in the `SELECT` list where the query is not introduced with 'EXISTS'.

I am trying to get the recent games won from the last three games.

Thanks

```
DECLARE @RecentGamesWon INT

SET @RecentGamesWon = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                       FROM game g
                       JOIN inserted ON inserted.HomeTeamID = g.HomeTeamID
                       WHERE g.HomeTeamID IN (SELECT TOP 3 * 
                                              FROM game g
                                              WHERE (g.hometeamid = inserted.HomeTeamID 
                                                     AND g.HomeScore >  g.AwayScore)
                                                 OR (g.awayteamid = inserted.HomeTeamID 
                                                     AND g.AwayScore > g.HomeScore)
                       ORDER BY g.GameDate));
```

Comment: so if the problem isnt in the SELECT list at the top have you considered the other SELECT?

Comment: You need to select `top 3 HomeTeamID` instead of `top 3 *`

Comment: Guessing this is on a trigger too. Why does your trigger assume there will only be 1 row in `inserted`? (hint: it shouldn't.)

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce your problem statement, because i would require the data with proper table structure. Please provide the variable tables with the data what you are using, with you problem statements.

BUT, for a while you can try by correcting your existing query i.e. use `TOP 3 HomeTeamID` rather than `TOP 3 *`.

And if problem still persists, then use `CTE` to have your inner query results and then set the count from CTE to your desired variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return two (or multiple) columns in your subquery to do the comparison in the WHERE A_ID IN (subquery) clause - which column is it supposed to compare A_ID to? Your subquery must only return the one column needed for the comparison to the column on the other side of the IN. So the query needs to be of the form:

```
SELECT * From ThisTable WHERE ThisColumn IN (SELECT ThatColumn FROM ThatTable)
```

In your query, this is the portion failing -

```
... WHERE g.HomeTeamID IN (SELECT TOP 3 * FROM game g ...
```

**To fix** - Your query should be as follows -

```
SET @RecentGamesWon = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                       FROM game g
                       JOIN inserted ON inserted.HomeTeamID = g.HomeTeamID
                       WHERE g.HomeTeamID IN (SELECT TOP 3 g.HomeTeamID
                                              FROM game g
                                              WHERE (g.hometeamid = inserted.HomeTeamID 
                                                     AND g.HomeScore >  g.AwayScore)
                                                 OR (g.awayteamid = inserted.HomeTeamID 
                                                     AND g.AwayScore > g.HomeScore)
                       ORDER BY g.GameDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want:

```
SELECT @RecentGamesWon COUNT(*) 
FROM inserted i CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 3 g.*
      FROM game g
      WHERE i.HomeTeamID IN (g.hometeamid, g.awayteamid)
      ORDER BY g.GameDate DESC
     ) g
WHERE (g.hometeamid = i.HomeTeamID AND g.HomeScore >  g.AwayScore) OR
      (g.awayteamid = i.HomeTeamID AND g.AwayScore > g.HomeScore);
```

This selects the 3 most recent games played by `i.HomeTeamID` and t hen counts the number of wins.